# Update quantity of the same item in the session instead of adding new one

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, joomla-api, session

I use the following code in my controller for adding product items to the session:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;
$itemid = $input->get('itemid');
$quan = $input->get('quan');
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$cart = $session->get('cart', array());
$cart['items'][] = array('itemid' => $itemid, 'quan' => $quan);
$session->set('cart', $cart);
```

It works, but if I add the same product with the same ID to the session once more it doesn't update the quantity of such product but adds the same product as new item. So I need something like:

```
if($itemid == 'itemid') {
    $cart['items'][] = array('quan' => 'quan'+$quan); // i.e. current quan + new quan
} else {
    $cart['items'][] = array('itemid' => $itemid, 'quan' => $quan);
}
```

It doesn't work of course

Comment: Don't have time to answer, but since PHP array is and ordered map, can't you just make the items array a map from 'itemid' => 'quan'? This map would be trivial to search and update by itemid. I assume you had some reason for adding the extra layer of data structure, though?

Comment: @Ville Niemi: yes that was exactly my suggestion too. I also have an example how to update that map in my answer...

Comment: @fruppel Guess I should have checked your answer for that update... Well, no harm done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution A: Slightly adjusted array structure

You have only your itemid and the corresponding quantity in your array. Why don't you use the itemid as array index ($cart['items'][<ITEMID>]) so you could easily update your quantity if the index already exists.

```
$cart['items'][100] = 10
$cart['items'][236] = 5
  your itemid --^     ^-- your quantity
```

Something like

```
if (isset($cart['items'][$itemid]))
{
    $cart['items'][$itemid] = $cart['items'][$itemid] + $quan;
}
else 
{
    $cart['items'][$itemid] = $quan;
}
```

### Solution B: Loop through existing array structure

Otherwise you have to loop through your array, find the item with the right itemid and update its quantity, like this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;
$itemid = $input->get('itemid');
$quan = $input->get('quan');
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$cart = $session->get('cart', array());
$found = false;

if (isset($cart['items']) && !empty($cart['items']))
{
    foreach ($cart['items'] as &$item)
    {
        if ($item['itemid'] == $itemid)
        {
            $item['quan'] += $quan;
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (!$found) 
{
    $cart['items'][] = array('itemid' => $itemid, 'quan' => $quan);
}

$session->set('cart', $cart);
```

Comment: When I try solution A category of products is being added to the session instead of product and I get the following record in my session: `s:4:"cart";a:1:{s:5:"items";a:2:{i:2;i:2;i:3;s:1:"1";}}}` (category has ID 1 and is stored in the same table, probably solution A adds incorrect ID i.e. itemid)

Comment: It's more a general idea how one could use a map to achieve the same easier than a ready-to-use solution. I do not know the details of your code and it could be that you have to modify other parts of your code as well for solution A. If solution B works for you, just go with it :-)